# why do boost futures return different values?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I want to write a code where I use boost futures and threads to compute several functions in parallel:

The function is named 'function' that takes on 'inputs', and I want to store the function return values in a vector named 'results'

CODE 1 (part only of the main code):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < max_iter; i++) {
          boost::shared_future<double>> future = boost::async(boost::launch::async,boost::bind(&function,input));
          results[i] = future.get();}
```

But I would like to let the threads run in parallel, so I tried doing this code which stores the futures in a vector and then gets the results as soon as all futures are ready. I used the wait_for_all function from boost to wait for threads to get finished..

CODE 2 (part only of the main code):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < max_iter; i++) {
                      boost::shared_future<double>> future = boost::async(boost::launch::async,boost::bind(&function,input));
                      future_buffer.push_back(future);

    boost::wait_for_all(future_buffer.begin(), future_buffer.end())

    for (int l = 0; l < max; l++) {
        results[l] = future_buffer[l].get()
    }
```

I got to comply both CODE 1 and CODE 2, but am getting different results... I checked and CODE 1 gives the right results but CODE 2 doesn't, and I couldn't figure out why?... what am I missing here...?

Comment: Please  post a complete, verifiable example and state what you expect for output

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the body of `function`, so we can't know for sure. But there's a obvious guess.

Your first code is doing everything sequentially. It also has a large amount of overhead of starting threads and then immediately waiting for them to end. It is otherwise the same as

```
for (int i = 0; i < max_iter; i++) {
    results[i] = function(input);
}
```

Your second code is (probably) doing things in parallel. It sounds like you have data shared between all the calls to `function`, and change in one thread invalidate the data seen in another.